# How to set path for downloading via savefileto add-on with c# and selenium

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, firefox-addon

I am trying to change path of download folder in savefileto (savefileto@mozdev.org) FF add-on, and it doesn't work...

```
profile.SetPreference("extensions.savefileto@mozdev.org.page.recent", "[{\"type\":\"folder\",\"label\":\"pearlcrescent\",\"path\":\"C:\\temp\\pearlcrescent\",\"menu\":false}]
```

This is exactly what I need set to add-on, before starting FF.

I tried these:

```
\" || "" || ' || \x22
```

no succes...

When I set it in FF, it looks like:

```
extensions.savefileto@mozdev.org.page.recent; type":"folder","label":"pearlcrescent","path":"C:\\temp\\pearlcrescent","menu":false}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the dowloading folder by `setPreference` samely as you did:

```
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", "c:\\download");
```